# Recurrence of Task in Opportunity object

Tags: process-builder, opportunity

Hi everyone I am new to Salesforce

I am facing some issue. When I change stage value in opportunity to Qualification, some task should be created but after some time again I made changes the stage values like Qualification to prospecting and again prospecting to Qualification there is a repetition of Task again which I don't want to create.

How can I do that in Process Builder? I want to create a task only one time for one stage value even I do changes repeatedly. And I set the value of repeat the task to Task closed.

Note: I have to do this in process builder only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really bound to use only Process Builder, you would need to add a field to the Opportunity object, such as `Created_Qualification_Task__c` (checkbox). Your Process Builder can then perform a record update to set that box to True when you create the task, and alter your entry criteria to check the value of the checkbox before you create any records.

There are various alternate solutions that might or might not be better depending on the totality of your business requirements, such as using a Validation Rule to prevent stages from being updated in a backwards direction or using a Flow to query for a Task.